# Windows logon screen not always displayed after screen saver activated

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

I've set screen saver settings to turn on after 60 minutes and "on resume, display logon screen". When I returned in the morning, I was brought to the desktop without a logon screen. However, I just changed it to turn on after 1 minute for testing, and I do get a password prompt after screen saver was activated. What can I do to get the logon screen every time?

Comment: Was the screen saver running when you returned in the morning? It's possible that your power settings put the machine into stand-by (aka sleep) mode before the screen saver timer started.

Comment: My monitor was off, so I couldn't determine that. I don't recall whether it was in sleep mode or not, but it's possible that sleep mode is causing these problems, because I'm currently unable to put the computer into sleep mode despite setting it to do so after 1 min. If I don't figure out why sleep mode doesn't work, I should  probably just disable it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'Lock' your screen when you leave (ctrl+alt+del) to be sure that whoever uses the PC next has to log in.

There are a few things which can stop a screensaver from locking a session, possible windows/program updates may interrupt it... Or even a program waiting for a response/notification.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Del won't actually lock the PC. To lock it use WinKey + L

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Del alone won't lock the computer at all, but it will provide you a menu that includes locking the computer.

Comment: Winkey+L can be hard to remember, but ctrl+alt+del everyone can... Personally I use cntrl+alt+del and just hit enter :)